# C++ Binary Search Tree Insertion functions

Tags: c++, pointers, search, binary-tree

Helly everyone,

I took a C++ coding course with practically no prior knowledge(my understanding of pointers is still somewhat shakey)at University this semester.
I have to implement a binary search tree in C++ and my problem is as follows:
Over a predefined Node structure with values and pointers to a left and a right node I am supposed to implement several functions, two of them being:

```
void InsertNode(Node* root, Node* node)
```

which is supposed to fit the handed node into the given tree "root",
and another one called

```
void InsertValue(Node* root, int value)
```

which should create a new instance of the node struct with the passed value and fit it in the given tree "root". To do so I am supposed to use both CreateNode (simple function to create Node* pointer of a new Node instance with int value and left/right pointers set to NULL) and InsertNode.

Im kind of running in a treadmill here and i dont think i really understand how the functions are supposed to work(eg. the difference between them).
Yesterday i wrote this function:

```
void InsertNode(Node* root, Node* node){
    if(root == NULL){
        root = CreateNode(node->value);
    }
    else if(root->value < node->value){
        if(node->left != NULL){
             InsertNode(root, node->left);
        }
        else{
             node->left = CreateNode(root->value);
        }
    }
    else if(root->value > node->value){
        if(node->right != NULL){
             InsertNode(root, node->right);
        }
        else{
            node->right = CreateNode(root->value);
        }
    }
}
```

Since im not really able to test these functions without the later functions that will actually build the tree with given nodes i was curious if i could get some help here with the next functions InsertValue(what is it supposed to do that InsertNode doesnt do already? :S)

Greetings and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Initial note: This answer assumes that the `InsertNode` function is initially called with `root` being the root of the tree, and `node` being the node to insert into the tree.

---

One problem is this statement:

```
root = CreateNode(node->value);
```

Since the argument `root` is passed by value, which means that it is copied, the assignment will only change the local copy. Once the function returns the original pointer that you pass to the function will not have changed.

You need to pass the pointer *by reference*, meaning the `root` argument references the original variable passed in to the function, instead of it being copied. You do this by using an ampersand when declaring the argument:

```
Node*& root
```

The above means that `root` is a reference to a pointer to `Node`.

So the complete `InsertNode` declaration should look like

```
void InsertNode(Node*& root, Node* node)
```

---

There are also other problems, for example these lines are not correct:

```
if(node->left != NULL){
     InsertNode(root, node->left);
}
else{
     node->left = CreateNode(root->value);
}
```

This is not correct because `node->left` should be `NULL` always, which makes you create a new node using the value from the `root` of the tree, and assign it to `node->left`, but you never insert `node` in the tree.

What you should instead do is simply

```
InsertNode(node->left, node);
```

Of course you should do the same change for setting the right branch.

---

Combining the two solutions above, your function would look like

```
void InsertNode(Node*& root, Node* node)
{
    if (root == 0)
        root = node;
    else if (root->value < node->value)
        InsertNode(root->left, node);
    else
        InsertNode(root->right, node);
}
```

This function also solves a third problem with your current code: What if `node->value` is *equal* to `root->value`? The above function puts it in the right branch.

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating a tree, value are also assigned with each node. See following code:

```
typedef struct BST {
   int data;
   struct BST *lchild, *rchild;
} node;


void insert(node *root, node *new_node) {
   if (new_node->data < root->data) {
      if (root->lchild == NULL)
         root->lchild = new_node;
      else
         insert(root->lchild, new_node);
   }

   if (new_node->data > root->data) {
      if (root->rchild == NULL)
         root->rchild = new_node;
      else
         insert(root->rchild, new_node);
   }
}

node *new_node, *root;

int main()
{ 
        new_node = get_node();
        printf("\nEnter The Element ");
        scanf("%d", &new_node->data);

        if (root == NULL) /* Tree is not Created */
           root = new_node;
        else
           insert(root, new_node)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code is in Python and is used for insertion in a BST ::

```
class Node :
    def __init__(self.key):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.val = key

def insert(root.node):
    if root is None :
        root = node
    else :
        if root.val < node.val:
            if root.right is None :
                root.right = node
            else :
                insert(root.right, node)
        else :
            if root.left is None :
                root.left = node
            else :
                insert(root.left, node)

def inorder(root):
    if root :
        inorder(root.left)
        print(root.val)
        inorder(root.right)

# Driver program to test the above functions
# Let us create the following BST
#      50
#    /    \
#   30     70
#   / \    / \
#  20 40  60 80
r = Node(50)
insert(r,Node(30))
insert(r,Node(20))
insert(r,Node(40))
insert(r,Node(70))
insert(r,Node(60))
insert(r,Node(80))

# Print inoder traversal of the BST
inorder(r)
```